# How to weight my data in SAS - categorical and numerical variables

Tags: categorical-data, sas, weighted-data

I've collected data from 1000 animals (categorical and numerical variables) from 2 different farms. My problems are: one farm corresponds to 68% of my data, in some of my variables I've observed more animals in one category than in another (eg. more animals in breeding than animals in gestation). Im using SAS and I ran *proc freq* to analyze *chi-square* result. Its showing relationships between my variables but the problem is how can I interpret this relationship when I have categories in each variable and my chi-square graphs are no showing any significant difference? I need to **weight my data** but I have no idea how to do it. If someone can help me here... thanks! if you need more info or if I wasn't clear enough let me know!

Comment: Your question, stripped of apparently inessential details, appears to ask "when I don't observe a significant difference, how can I change my analysis or my data to make it look significant?"  Would this be a fair summary of it?

Comment: oh, okay.. yes, that is a fair summary. thank you